# UIViewController inside another UIViewController, is it possible?

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm making a newsstand app and I need multiple components in a single view. I have a `UIViewController` that displays and manages a pdf (zooming, scrolling,etc...) but I don't want it to be full screen instead I want it to be like an `UIView` inside another `UIViewController` which has a menu on top, page numbering on the bottom and other tools. Both are subclass of `UIViewController`... I already have both working separately. I just want the pdf viewer inside the other. Is it possible? here's some code of what I want (lets say is inside the `viewDidLoad`)... but obviously doesn't work. Any help is appreciated. It also must be IOS 5.1.1 compatible and above

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myPdf" ofType:@"pdf"];
    PDFViewController *page = [[PDFViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtPath:path];
    //pdfView is a UIView of size 600x600 right in the middle
    [self setPdfView:[page view]]; //this doest work... but it's basically what I want instead of presenting a viewController
    //[self presentViewController:page animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I'm also aware of this, but I don't understand... if this is the way I would like some guidance:

```
addChildViewController:
willMoveToParentViewController:
didMoveToParentViewController:
```

Comment: Read the reference docs for `UIViewController` as well as the `View Controller Programming Guide for iOS`. Both talk about "implementing a container view controller".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As of iOS 5 you can do View Controller Containment which lets you add child view controllers into a parent view controller. The child view controllers can manage all the logic like they normally would but the view of the child controller can match any frame/position you like.

To add the controller you can do

```
   [self addChildViewController:childViewController];             
   childViewController.view.frame = [self frameForChildController];
   [self.view addSubview:childViewController.view];
   [childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

You can learn more about it in the [View Controller Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6)

Comment: This is correct, I would also recommend use always the storyboard before doing it in code, is by far a much better approach.

here is a good link: http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers

Comment: I don't see how doing it in a storyboard is a 'far better approach' at all.